# Children's book involving a pet pig (probably named Percy) and moving a house

Tags: identification-request

The story involves a young child (a girl, I think) who receives a baby pig as a pet.  I'm pretty sure she named the pig "Percy" which is a problem, as there is a whole series of "Percy the Pig" books which are unrelated and I recall the title of this book as "Percy the Pig".

As Percy grows up he eventually becomes too big to live in town, and an official (Mayor or Chief of Police?) says Percy has to go.  The family responds by moving the entire house to a country locale, while Percy sleeps on a rug in the living room.

The book includes a quite accurate technical description of how houses are moved; lifting the structure from the foundation, attaching it to a special truck, towing it along the highway, and setting it on a new foundation.

It was probably something from a Scholastic book fair in the 1960s.

Update: I managed to get a copy of "Pig in the Parlor" on interlibrary loan, and that's definitely the book.  What I remember most about this book is the detailed description of moving a house, which turns out to be accurate but nowhere near as detailed as I recall.  I guess that says something about where my mind was in 196x...

[image: Interestingly, the copy I got was a providing reviewer's copy, and still had the note to that effect stuck inside the front cover!]

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something from [Richard Scarry](https://www.richardscarry.com/books)?

Comment: 99+% certain it's not Richard Scarry.

Comment: Your recent edit has kind of put the answer into the question, which makes the post confusing for future readers. Could you add this concluding paragraph and image ([the image can now be linked from Imgur since you uploaded it into your post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jHun.jpg)) as a comment underneath Ayshe's answer instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pig in the Parlor* by Judy Varga

Excerpt from [Bulletin from Virginia Kirkus' Service, vol. 31,1963](https://books.google.com/books?hl=bg&id=ZFTpAAAAMAAJ):

> Percy, who wears a neat bow around his neck and a bib when he eats,
> who learns to balance a ball on his snout, but who grows very large
> and is forced to move from suburbia, will find many ready friends
> among young onlookers. The problem of Percy's dwelling place is easily
> solved when Mary Jane's parents tow their house from the town to the
> country-- and Percy is permitted to remain in the parlor.

Comment: This is absolutely the book.  Now, it's back to the local library to see if they can dig me up a copy.